# Can a Trac 0.12.3 textarea field span columns?

Tags: trac

Our old Trac installation was running version 0.11.5. We have just upgraded to 0.12.3 (rc1). On the old installation we had a custom textarea field for entering additional info separate from the description. I have recreated that field in 0.12.3.

In 0.11.5 it used to span both columns of the ticket. In 0.12.3 it takes up only one column. Some searching revealed some tickets and discussion about layout, but more complex than what I'm talking about.

How can I make a textarea span both columns like it did in 0.11.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `field.rows = 2`. Here is an example as it would be used in trac.ini:

```
[ticket-custom]
release_note = textarea
release_note.cols = 60
release_note.label = Release Note
release_note.order = 0
release_note.rows = 2
```

Comment: Don't confuse columns and rows of the ticket fields box with columns and rows inside the text area input field. Per-field configuration options are clearly dedicated to the latter. Didn't verify in source yet, but if the field width (in .cols) is big enough the field should automatically span both field columns in the ticket box, right? I don't recall a similar problem with my own custom text area - worked instantly.

Comment: @hasienda I think you are right. Means the example above works because of the `field.cols = 60`. Though I am not able to verify it at this moment.